# Como dar merge nesses 2 dataframes e filtrando o timestamp mais recente para valores repetidos?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

Eu tenho 2 dataframes que gostaria de mergear

DF1:

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date       Admission D/T  \
0    1          1234       John       Doe  01/02/1999  04/12/2002 5:00 PM   
1    2          2345     Joanne       Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 7:22 PM   
2    3          3456  Annabelle     Jones  01/02/2001  04/21/2002 5:00 PM   

         Discharge D/T          Update D/T  
0  04/13/2002 10:00 PM  04/24/2002 6:00 AM  
1   04/20/2002 6:22 AM  04/24/2002 6:00 AM  
2   04/23/2002 2:53 AM  04/24/2002 6:00 AM
```

DF2:

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name Last Name  Birth Date       Admission D/T  \
0   20           987      Jerry     Jones  01/02/1988  05/01/2002 2:00 PM   
1    2          2345     Cosmia       Lee  04/19/2002  04/19/2002 7:22 PM   
2    3          3456  Annabelle     Jones  01/02/2001  04/21/2002 5:00 PM   

        Discharge D/T          Update D/T  
0  05/02/2002 9:00 PM  05/17/2002 6:00 AM  
1  04/20/2002 6:22 AM  05/17/2002 6:00 AM  
2  04/23/2002 2:53 AM  05/17/2002 6:00 AM
```

Os 2 Dataframes tem pontos de intersecção, como o registro 2 de cada df,

```
MRN  Encounter ID First Name        Last Name  Birth Date       Admission D/T       Discharge D/T 
2    3          3456    Annabelle   Jones      01/02/2001       04/21/2002 5:00 PM  04/23/2002 2:53 AM
```

em que todos os valores são iguais, exceto o "Update D/T" ( no df2 o valor é mais recente - 05/17/2002 6:00 AM)

É possível mesclar os 2 dataframes e para o registros repetidos pegar o valor mais atualizado do Update D/T ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se este é o caso real, a solução seria realizar as seguintes etapas:

1. merge dos dois dataframes usando as colunas `MRN`, `Encounter ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name` e `Birth Date` com:

```
df_merged = pandas.merge(df1, dfs2, on=["MRN", "Encounter ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Birth Date"])
```

Por padrão, o pandas irá colocar um sufixo para os campos que existem nos dois dataframes, mas não fazem parte do `on=`. Neste caso, o campo `Admission D/T` ficará 'Admission D/T_x' para dados do df1 e 'Admission D/T_y' para dados do df2.

2. Criar a coluna `Admission D/T` em `df_merged` contendo o maior valor entre 'Admission D/T_x' e 'Admission D/T_y'. Algo como:

```
df_merged['Admission D/T'] = np.where(df['Admission D/T_x'] > df['Admission D/T_y'], df['Admission D/T_x'], df['Admission D/T_y'])
```

**Nota**: a condição dentro do `np.where` pode ser uma função.

3. Apagar as colunas

```
df.drop(['Admission D/T_x', 'Admission D/T_y'], axis=1)
```

Espero que ajude