# Python - DataFrame - Criar um novo DataFrame a partir da comparação de outros dois DataFrame

Tags: python, comparação, dataframe

estou com uma dúvida e gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Tenho dois DataFrame e preciso comparar se algumas colunas destes DataFrame são iguais e, caso sejam iguais, então preciso armazenar esse registro em um outro dataFrame. Ou seja, eu preciso criar um novo DataFrame a partir da comparação de outros dois.
O exemplo é referente ao df1 e df2 (preciso comparar 4 critérios - gender, age, raca e escolaridade) e após a comparação criar o df3 com os registros que foram verdadeiros na comparação. No caso do exemplo abaixo, o df3 seria formado pelo registro de índice 0 do df1 e e pelo registro do índice 0 df2, já que são iguais nos critérios mencionados.

```
import pandas as pd

 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"gender": ['f','m','f'],
                        "age": [11,22,39], 
                        "raca": ['C','nC','nC'], 
                        "escolaridade": ['F','S','M'],
                        "var1":["yes", "yes", "no"],
                        "var2":["no", "yes", "yes"],
                        "var3":["no", "no", "no"],
                        "classe":["no", "yes", "no"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"gender": ['f','f','m'],
                        "age": [11,22,40], 
                        "raca": ['C','C','nC'], 
                        "escolaridade": ['F','M','M'],
                        "var1":["yes", "yes", "no"],
                        "var2":["no", "no", "yes"],
                        "var3":["no", "no", "yes"],
                        "classe":["yes", "yes", "no"]})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem uma amostra dos *DataFrames* e um [mcve] da sua tentativa mesmo não funcionando? Provavelmente seu problema deve ser resolvido com [`DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) mas sem ver a lógica do que está fazendo fica difícil afirmar.

Comment: Lili, como não temos o caso real aqui, dê uma olhada neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/474128/como-dar-merge-nesses-2-dataframes-e-filtrando-o-timestamp-mais-recente-para-val/475738#475738)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o método `merge` resolverá o problema

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])
```

Para maiores detalhes veja a documentação [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Nota: qualquer outra coluna que tenha o nome repetido nos dois dataframes receberão os sufixos `_x` para o primeiro df e `_y` para o segundo df. Os sufixos podem ser passados como parâmetro no `pd.merge` caso necessário `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[col1, col2, col3], suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3],
                        "y": [1,2,3], 
                        "z": [1,2,3], 
                        "w": [1,2,3], 
                        "outra":["primeiro", "df", "esquerda"]})

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3], 
                        "y": [1,2,3], 
                        "z": [1,2,3], 
                        "w": [3,3,3], 
                        "outra":["segundo", "df", "direita"]})

>>> df1
   x  y  z  w     outra
0  1  1  1  1  primeiro
1  2  2  2  2        df
2  3  3  3  3  esquerda

>>> df2
   x  y  z  w    outra
0  1  1  1  3  segundo
1  2  2  2  3       df
2  3  3  3  3  direito

>>> df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["x", "y", "z", "w"], suffixes=["_df1", "_df2"])

>>> df3
   x  y  z  w outra_df1 outra_df2
0  3  3  3  3  esquerda   direita
>>>
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: o problema é que preciso manter a variável de identificação, pois é importante para o meu problema. Além das variáveis de comparação, os DataFrame tem mais 51 variáveis cada. E eu preciso "pegar" os registros por meio de determinadas condições, por exemplo, se são do mesmo sexo, se são da mesma idade e outras características. Dessa maneira, preciso criar um DataFrame com esses registros.

Comment: Os registros que são chave, permanecerão com seu nome. lembre-se sempre que vc pode usar o `dataframe.columns` para ver o nome das colunas do dataframe.
O filtro pode ser feito com `dataframe[(CONDIÇÃO_AQUI)]`

Comment: Se vc der um exemplo dos dois dataframes ficará mais fácil de te ajudar com isso.

Comment: Eu estou pedindo esse exemplo desde o primeiro comentário.

Comment: O df1 tem 200 registros e 50 variáveis. O df2 tem 1700 registros e 50 variáveis. Eu preciso comparar df1 e df2 e verificar quais os registros (entre df1 e df2) que tem o mesmo gênero, idade, escolaridade e raça. Ao comparar, é necessário que esses registros que apresentam as mesmas característica citadas, sejam armazenados em outro df. Porém, preciso preservar todas as variáveis, ou seja, as 50 variáveis. Muito obrigada pelo apoio.

Comment: Só uma amostra de três linhas de cada DF mais a estrutura. Senão não tem como responder.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, talvez com a explicação acima, eu tenha conseguido esclarecer melhor.  Obrigada.

Comment: Entendo que os dados devam ser sigilosos. Neste caso, use o que passei como resposta para servir de base para seu caso específico. Pense em `x` como genero, `y` como idade, `z` como escolaridade e `w` como raça..